# different label in header depending on section in collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

```
 let titles = ["Popularity","Top Rated","Release Date","Revenue"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Header.identifier, for: indexPath) as! Header 
    header.label.text = titles[indexPath.section]
    return header
}
```

What I want to do header's text will be different according to titles array in every section. I can see the blank in view for header but there is no title in it.

Here is my Header class:

```
class Header: UICollectionReusableView {
static let identifier = "Header"

let label = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    label.frame = bounds
}
}
```

Also in viewDidLoad(), I wrote this.

```
collectionV.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Header.identifier)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to add label as subView in Header.

Comment: Ow, that's right. Thank you.